# SQL: How to return records with more than 1 row of data

Tags: sql

I'm stuck on a problem where I am creating a report and need to show records which have two or more bank accounts (some of our employees are international and get paid in more than one currency).

The report I created brings back all employees and their bank account information. However, I want this report ***only*** to bring back employees with 2 or more bank accounts.

Here is some test data below:

As you can see, **Gareth** has more than one bank account - what filter can I write to just bring back his record?

Comment: Don't throw in sample data as image. Instead post them as text. What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the query you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts-table  WHERE same-user-predicate AND different-account-predicate)` should work in any sql DBMS. Follow advices above if more help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is mysql, sqlite and even postgresql (I think). it should be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE "First Name" = "Gareth";
```

However if you are using the MySQL binding for excel be sure that "Gareth" is listed for each account he owns. It may look cleaner but SQL will interpret the row beneath "Gareth" as "". Doing this will also mean you will need a new index, "First Name" can't be set as "UNIQUE". Also having spaces in columns is pretty ugly SQL syntax best to use camelCase or under_scores.

Comment: Oops typo. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Person_Number` as the primary key of the table `accounts`

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accounts.First_Name in
(SELECT a.First_Name
 FROM accounts a
 INNER JOIN accounts b
 ON a.Person_Number = b.Person_Number
 WHERE a.First_Name = b.First_Name
 AND a.Bank_Account_Name <> b.Bank_Account_Name
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using database like oracle, sqlserver....

```
select b1.* from account_info_table b1 where exists (select 1 from account_info_table b2 where b1.first_name=b2.first_name group by b2.first_name having count(*)>2);
```

or

```
select * from account_info_table where first_name in (select first_name from account_info_table group by first_name having count(*)>2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This Code : 
;WITH _CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName Order By FirstName)ROWNO FROM  @Temp
)SELECT FirstName,BankAccountName,BankBranchName,BankAccountNo,SortCode FROM _CTE WHERE ROWNO > 1
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: one person have multiple account of multiple banks..we have individual column of the record in our data and put on partition to particular column when we get more than one record of the person...we are using partition as per our needs

Answer (score 0):

select empleado from empleados
group by empleado
having count(*) > 1